# SetState secound parameter callback function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My issue rely on that I can't invoke a second parameter of setState react function.

I do know that it is asynchronous function and it has its own rules but something is wrong and I am stuck here

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        mainArray: []
    };
    let array=[];
    for(let i=0;i<20;i++){
        let children=[];
        for(let j=0;j<20;j++){
            children.push(<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square1}`}/>);
        }   
    array.push(<div key={`${i}`}>{children}</div>);     
    }
    this.setState({mainArray: array},function (){console.log('message');}); 
    console.log(this.state.mainArray);
}
```

The message isn't showed in the console and the last line does show only empty array

Comment: I see 'array' appearing twice, used like a variable name, but with no declaration - surely that's not what you intended?

Comment: 1: You have to console.log in your second parameter of setState or you'll log the old state. 2: when you do array.push array var does not exists. 3: You have to enclose  your code (for...to console.log) in a method

Comment: it were global array but copied to constructor still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be calling `setState` in the constructor. `setState` triggers a component's lifecycle which the constructor is already part of. So maybe you are messing with the lifecycle.

What happens when you call that `setState` in `componentDidMount`?

Also, in the construction **you don't need setState**. In the constructor, and in the constructor only, you can write the state directly:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    const array = [];

    for(const i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        let children = [];
        for(let j = 0; j < 20; j++){
            children.push(<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square1}`}/>);
        }   
        array.push(<div key={`${i}`}>{children}</div>);     
    }

    this.state = { mainArray: array };

    console.log(this.state.mainArray);
}
```